# iOS 13 - Cordova azure notification hubs plugin not registered device

Tags: ios, azure, cordova, push-notification, ios13

after the last iOS update the **cordova-azure-notification-hubs** stopped working, not allowing iOS 13 devices to receive notifications. I attached the initial registration event that is no longer receiving the registration id.

```
const notification = PushNotification.init(
   {
      notificationHubPath: 'xxxxxxxxx',
      connectionString: 'xxxxxxxxx',
      launch: true,
      android: {
        sound: true,
        forceShow: true,
      },
      ios: {
        alert: 'true',
        badge: true,
        sound: 'false'
      }
   });

notification.on('registration', data => {
   console.log('deviceUUID = ' + data.registrationId);
});
```

This plugin is originally based on an old version of the **phonegap-plugin-push plugin**, which if it was correctly updated for iOS 13, however it has not given good results either. I have followed the documentation of this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-push but still do not register the device.
Any ideas about it? I appreciate your help and comments.

Comment: iOS13 introduces a change to how the token is returned to the system, most likely this plugin will need to be updated.

Comment: Could you manually update the cordova-azure-notification-hubs plugin, replacing the files that were modified for ios 13 in the phonegap-plugin-push plugin? what you think about this? @DawsonLoudon